# Counting the number of vowels in a string and returning the count Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner and my objective is this - Write a function called count_vowels that accepts a string argument that represents a word and returns the number of vowels that are in the word.

Heres my code so far to explain:

```
string = 'oboe'
def count_vowels(string):
    count = 0
    
    if 'a' or 'A' in string:
        count += 1
    if 'e' or 'E' in string:
        count += 1
    if 'i' or 'I' in string:
        count += 1
    if 'o' or 'O' in string:
        count += 1
    if 'u' or 'U' in string:
        count += 1
    return count
print(count_vowels(string))
```

Where i am a bit lost is the output value. If you run this code with the word 'oboe' you get 5. makes no sense So i was wondering, do elif statements change the output? Besides that, what would I need to alter in my code to have it work properly. I feel like something is being iterated upon too many times.

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The if-conditions in form `if 'a' or 'A' in string:` etc. are always evaluating to `True`.  It should be `if ('a' in string) or ('A' in string):`.

Also, it's necessary to evaluate these conditions in a loop, to get correct answer.

Here is example with `sum()` builtin:

```
def count_vowels(string):
    return sum(ch in 'aeiou' for ch in string.lower())

print(count_vowels('oboe'))
```

Prints:

```
3
```

Comment: Thank you, its easy to evaluate whats its doing when its in one line compared to 8!